# ActionBar Menu Icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem

I'm wondering how can I add icons to the actionbar menu, that means not the actionbar itself but when you press on the menu button you actually opens a spinner with text only.
In the Galaxy SIII Samsung somehow implemented in their apps icons in this spinner.
So, is that possible, and if so how exactly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [ActionProviders](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider). It will allow you to have your own `MenuItem` with it's own `Action`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/1460581) you have an example (an App Picker menu)

Comment: I actually need this to support android 3.0 and up, action providers only introduced in android api 14